# Calculations on geometrical shapes in R

Tags: r, geometry

I would like to display and do some calculations (e.g. area, size) on geometrical shapes that intersect, in R. Can someone tell me how to do that? (previous wording "can someone recommend a suitable package for that" resulted in the question being closed, but that's really all I need, I am familiar with analytical geometry).

Extensive research on the internet resulted in loads of material about geographical objects and spherical geometry. Here I am interested in plain 2D shapes in cartesian coordinates only.

A simple example would be nice: a circle and a rectangle (size and position not importand) intersecting, and area and radius of the smallest surrounding circle of the intersection area being estimated.

I could use an image analysis library for the job and be ready immediately, but R really is the preferred tool for the following evaluations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `sf` package. While this package is most often used for geospatial data, it can also handle geometric intersections. Let me provide a basic example of calculating overlap of a rectangle and oval-like shape. I'll also use `plotrix` package briefly to generate data for an oval-like shape, since you didn't put sample data in your question.

```
library(sf)
plot(0)
#make a oval, then put oval points in a dataframe
oval<-plotrix::draw.circle( 0, 0, .5 ) %>% data.frame(.)

#combine oval data points into an sf object. Convert points to polygon
oval_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(oval, coords = c("x", "y")) %>% 
  sf::st_combine(.) %>% 
  sf::st_cast(., "POLYGON")

#Make a rectangle. I make a 1 X 1.5 rectangle in the example.
rectangle <-sf::st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0, 0, 1.5, 1.5, 0), c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0))))

#Sum of area of the two separate shapes
total_area <- st_area(rectangle) + st_area(oval_sf)
#Sum of area of two shapes if combined into one shape
combined_area<-st_area(st_union(oval_sf,rectangle))
#Then calculate the area of the intersection
intersection_area <- total_area - combined_area
intersection_area
[1] 0.4716912
```

For examples illustrating more complex intersections within `sf`, have a look at:
https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_ops.html

Comment: Thank you, also for the reference to the examples. That seems to be what I am looking for.

Comment: Would like to add this question about finding the smallest enclosing circle  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388510/creating-smallest-circle-covering-polygon-using-r-with-sf .

Comment: I've just added an answer that question on gis.stackexchange.com addressing the "smallest enclosing circle" part of your question using `sf`.